# code for data when passing through an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I am passing this array through ajax, but not quite sure it should be expressed in the data section.

```
<input type="button" data-cats="{"type":"commercial","sub":"humidity","main":"wireless-sensors"}" id="button" value="click"><input type="text" value="21" id="no_value">
```

The array is actually coming from `json_encode($cats)`

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    cats = $(this).attr('data-cats');
    no_val = $('no_val').val()
    $.ajax({        
        type    : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url     : 'ajax.php',
        data    : 'cats='+cats+'&no_val='+no_val,
        success : function(data) {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Passing the array as `cats` doesnt seem to work. I assume its probably supposed to be some sort of json code, but I dont know what it should be.
I want to be able to extract the elements of the array in hte ajax.php file.

Comment: How to encode the data depends on how the receiving side expects it to be encoded.

Comment: Please also make sure you fix the typo in line 3: the id surely should read ´$('no_value')´ as in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" data-cats="{"type":"commercial","sub":"humidity","main":"wireless-sensors"}" id="button" value="click"><input type="text" value="21" id="no_value">
```

Is not valid HTML. The attribute is closed after the opening {. You could use single quotes instead.

Comment: No its fine, its `<input type="button" data-cats="'.json_encode($cats).'" id="button" value="click"><input type="text" value="21" id="no_value">`

Comment: @JackQueen: No, that's not fine.

Comment: then please be more constructive and tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Ok I changed it to `data-cats=\''.json_encode($this->cats).'\'`

Comment: And what's happening?